# How to perform expansions in a string in the context of a calling function in tcl

Tags: tcl

How can I implement `expand` in the script below (expanding commands and variables as normal in tcl), I want it to print out:

```
'
    hello {
        $b
    }
    {tcl world}
'
```

This is how I imagine the script will look:

```
proc clever_func {script} {
    set script [uplevel 1 expand [list $script]]
    puts "'$script'"
}

proc isolated_client_function {} {
    set a hello
    set b difficult
    set c tcl
    set d world

    clever_func {
        $a {
            $b
        }
        [list $c $d]
    }
}

isolated_client_function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example isn't a sufficient replacement for a specification, but it seems that there are no built-in TCL facility doing what you want. It would be possible to perform a substitution on a single *command tail* (by prepending `list` to a command and `eval`ling it at any level you want), but not for a pseudo-script with two "commands". (It's also possible to do what string interpolation does, using `subst`, but you probably already know why it's not what you want: it will also expand `$b`).

I see two possibilities to get what you want:

1. Tokenize your input using [`sugar::scriptToList`](http://wiki.tcl.tk/11158), then perform substitution manually in the list of tokens, then convert the result back to textual form with `sugar::listToScript`. These features of `sugar` macroprocessor are designed to let you modify scripts semantically while preserving formatting, comments and layout.
2. Break down your input into separate "commands": first split at each newline and semicolon, then use `info complete` to collect pieces corresponding to complete "commands" (IIRC there will be some corner cases with backslash-newline continuation: beware). On each complete "command" use the trick of prepending `"list "`, evaluating the result in necessary context (`uplevel`). Thus for each command you'll get a *list* where substitution has already been performed when appropiate. You will lose nuances of formatting inside each "command" (like the number of spaces separating words and the kind of space), and you will lose original command separators unless you take care to remember them yourself. It might not be bad for you if the goal is to get a kind of "pre-expanded script" to be `eval`uated later in some other context.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @anton-kovalenko. I will only use the $script variable in my example to execute commands (not to print them as I have done for the sake of having something to talk about), so if there is a way to convert $script so that the first command will be executed under `uplevel` and I can assign the remainder (the second, third, etc commands) back into $script and then repeat, then I will be a very happy bunny.

Comment: I'm finding the page of sugar documentation that you linked to be a very hard read. Is there any clearer reference material?

Comment: Parsing is the only way to achieve the desired effect. Two other pages to look at are [tclparser](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1660) and [parsetcl](http://wiki.tcl.tk/9649); I don't know which is easier to base off of. (Using `info complete` is just a variation on “parsing”.)

Answer (score 1):

The [`subst`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/subst.htm) command will take you most of the way there.

```
proc expand {script} {
    uplevel 1 [list subst $script]
}

set a hello
set b difficult
set c tcl
set d world

expand {
    $a {
        $b
    }
    [list $c $d]
}
```

outputs

```
    hello {
        difficult
    }
    tcl world
```

I'm not sure off the top of my head how to prevent `$b` from being substituted. You'll probably have to parse the script yourself.

If you want the last part to have the quoting you demonstrate, you need another level of list-ness

```
expand {
    $a {
        $b
    }
    [list [list $c $d]]
}
```

outputs

```
    hello {
        difficult
    }
    {tcl world}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I only thought I needed the extra level of quoting because the string will actually be used as a script, executed under namespace eval - which means it will be expanded again so I need to add the extra quoting inside clever_func.